# Error while using sbt-native-packager to get the docker support for my sbt project

Tags: scala, docker, plugins, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have added sbt-native-packager, version 1.3.15 in my plugins.sbt file.
in build.sbt file I am using enablePlugins(DockerPligin).
I am facing the below error when I am running the following command on sbt shell:

```
sbt>docker:publishLocal
```

ERROR -->

```
    [error] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "C:\Users\A674634\Desktop\Scala\playProjects\akka-cluster-playground\target\docker\stage"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    [error]         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:71)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$anonfun$runBuffered$1(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:150)
    [error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcI$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcI$sp.java:12)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anon$1.buffer(DockerPlugin.scala:348)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:150)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:116)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:355)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$30(DockerPlugin.scala:127)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$30$adapted(DockerPlugin.scala:125)
    [error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    [error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
    [error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
    [error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [error] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    [error]         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    [error]         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    [error]         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    [error]         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:71)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$anonfun$runBuffered$1(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:150)
    [error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcI$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcI$sp.java:12)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anon$1.buffer(DockerPlugin.scala:348)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:150)
    [error]         at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:116)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:355)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$30(DockerPlugin.scala:127)
    [error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$30$adapted(DockerPlugin.scala:125)
    [error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    [error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
    [error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
    [error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [IJ]sbt:akka-cluster-playground> [error] (Docker / publishLocal) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "C:\Users\A674634\Desktop\Scala\playProjects\akka-cluster-playground\target\docker\stage"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should execute that command in the project root folder. Which folder are you in now?

Comment: I have imported the project in Intellij and firing the mentioned command from sbt-shell.

Comment: in the error log: `in directory "C:\Users\A674634\Desktop\Scala\playProjects\akka-cluster-playground\target\docker\stage")`  . try to switch to root folder manually?

Comment: `You need the version 1.10 or higher of the docker console client installed. SBT Native Packager doesn’t use the REST API, but instead uses the CLI directly.` Check your local docker client version as well.